# How to use worker with locust command

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

How to use test time and number of users with docker-compose command

```
docker-compose up --scale worker=2
```

Or

How to use worker with locust command

```
locust -f --headless -u 1000 -r 100 --run-time 2m
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with docker-compose up command :-

Create docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  master:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master --headless -u 1000 -r 100 --run-time 20s

  worker:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host master



FROM command line run :- docker-compose up --scale worker=2
```

and this will run for specified duration i.e 20s